# Why does SELECT COUNT(1+'A') return 1 in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

As stated in the question, I am curious why is it on SQL Server when we do:

```
SELECT 1+'A'
```

It throws an error:

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'A' to data type int.

But when I do:

```
select count(1+'A')
```

I get a value of 1?

Why does it not throw an error?

Comment: What is the purpose of that query?

Comment: It is just a question to understand how SQL works. Why does the inner part of the query result in conversion type error but the count work, shouldn't that throw an error too?

Comment: I think Gordon explained it well in his answer. SQL is using the `Count()` function to count what's inside the parenthesis, not trying to give an answer of `1+'A'`.

Comment: The stream aggregate in the plan is doing `[Expr1001] = Scalar Operator(Count(*))`. With `SET ARITHABORT, ANSI_WARNINGS OFF;` you do get the error you were expecting, Presumably this logic is disabled for this case so things like `SELECT COUNT(1+'2147483647')` are handled correctly (evaluates to `NULL` with that setting on rather than throwing an error so `COUNT` needs to add up to zero)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apparently, SQL Server is smart enough to know that the count of a constant expression is either the same as `COUNT(*)` or `0`.  It can figure out that this is not `NULL` without actually evaluating it.

There are other cases where expressions are not evaluated.  For instance:

```
where not exists (select 1/0 from . . . )
```

Actually, I just learned something interesting.  These fail with a conversion error:

```
select count(1+'A'+NULL)
select count(1+'A'+nullif(1,1))
```

But this doesn't:

```
select count(1+'A'+nullif(1,0))
```

Seems like strange behavior to me, too.

Comment: The closest I can come to convincing myself that this is the answer is, somehow, under the hood, SQL is maybe converting the integer to a string and evaluating it a result which actually gives the count of 1; 

@Gordon Linoff, based on your learning, I tried the following:


`
select count(Null+'A')
select count(1+null+1)
`
Both of which return 0 (not 1!) 

Which is strange, because select count(NULL) definitely gives you:

Operand data type NULL is invalid for count operator.

Comment: @Akshay . . . That seems like an error to me.  I think the issue is an untyped `NULL` value, because this does return `0` as expected:  `select count(convert(int, null))`.